# How do I add additional text to subject using VBA in Word after referencing a table value from within the document?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, email

I have a macro that will create an email based on a word document.  The macro, once clicked, will save the word document, create an email with a predefined subject, add the recipient, create a brief message and then wait for the user to send.  The subject and body will even reference the first cell in a table within the word document.

I need to be able to add text in the subject after referencing the cell from the table.  But every time I add something after the referenced cell (from row 1, column 2), nothing appears.  When I do something similar to the body it looks like a new line is started after referencing the cell value.

How do I stop a new line from being created so I can reference two different items in the subject? The code I pasted should have a subject of "Customers Name [cell value] #Order Number [cell value]" but it only gives "Customers Name [cell value]".

Below is a copy of the code I am using with email addresses and things removed.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Doc
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument
On Error GoTo handler
    Doc.Save
On Error GoTo 0

 
With EmailItem
    .Display
    .Subject = "Customers Name " & Doc.Content.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2) & " #Order Number" & Doc.Content.Tables(1).Cell(1, 4)
    .Body = "Please see the attached Notification for " & Doc.Content.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2) & " order" & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "Let me know if you have any questions." & vbCrLf & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "Thank you," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "INSERT SIGNATURE HERE"
'Update Recipient List here:
    .To = "randomemail@email.com"
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal
    .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
End With
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end of the cell marker acts like an end of a paragraph mark and that is stopping the addition of anything else into the Subject of the email.

Add the following to your code after where you Set Doc = ActiveDocument:

```
Dim Rng1 As Word.Range, Rng2 As Word.Range
Set Rng1 = Doc.Content.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range
Rng1.MoveEnd unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
Set Rng2 = Doc.Content.Tables(1).Cell(1, 4).Range
Rng2.MoveEnd unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
```

And then replace the setting of the Subject code with this:

```
.Subject = "Customers Name " & Rng1.Text & " #Order Number" & Rng2.Text
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you Rich.  I noticed the extra space in the tables but wasn't sure how to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

There are two non-printing characters at the end of each cell. You need to remove them.

```
With Doc.Content.Tables(1)
    Customer = Left(.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text, Len(.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text) - 2)
    Order = Left(.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text, Len(.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text) - 2)
End With
```

Comment: Looks like this worked perfectly.  Thank you Timothy.  I noticed the extra space in the table but wasn't sure how to remove it.